# XML string element that contains XML tags within the value text

Tags: xml, tags

I want to have a string element with the following contents:

```
<UmlMessage>"@MainApp -> ControlThread : <font color=red><b>NET_SET_REQ</b>"</UmlMessage>
```

So the element UmlMessage value will be: `"@MainApp -> ControlThread : <font color=red><b>NET_SET_REQ</b>"`

I added the quotes, but that did not help. I get a strange error:

```
XMLSyntaxError: AttValue: " or ' expected, line 25, column 54
```

I assume it is to do with having XML-like tags in the value. But I want what is between the tags to be parsed as a string literal... is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**, assuming you don't really need the double quotes around the whole message, and you don't mind the contents of `UmlMessage` being parsed as XML:

```
<UmlMessage>@MainApp -> ControlThread : <font color="red"><b>NET_SET_REQ</b></font></UmlMessage>
```

**Option 2**, as above but with double quotes around message:

```
<UmlMessage>"@MainApp -> ControlThread : <font color='red'><b>NET_SET_REQ</b></font>"</UmlMessage>
```

**Option 3**, if you don't want the contents of `UmlMessage` to be parsed as XML, regardless of whether you require the surrounding quotes:

```
<UmlMessage><![CDATA["@MainApp -> ControlThread : <font color=red><b>NET_SET_REQ</b></font>"]]></UmlMessage>
```

BTW, even though browsers will tolerate missing delimiters around attribute values (`color=red`), I'd still recommend using them so that your markup is well-formed XML.  Similarly, I especially recommend explicitly closing the `font` element and have done so for you in the above examples.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the string content in a [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) element if it contains "problematic" characters:

```
<UmlMessage><![CDATA["@MainApp -> ControlThread : <font color=red><b>NET_SET_REQ</b>"]]></UmlMessage>
```